# shell EOF doesn't work with mysql command

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I changed all "'" and "`" to '"', some errors are gone but still not right
I edit the code and errors below

Part of my shell script is like this

```
#!/bin/bash
echo change $1 database
echo "Input dataBase password:"
read dbPasswd

if [ $1="Aa" ]; then
echo "Input old Aa ip:"
read oldAaip
echo "Input new Aa ip:"
read newAaip


mysql -uroot -p$dbPasswd << EOF
use Test_db
update "Test_controller" set node_ip = "$newAaip" where node_ip="$oldAaip";
update "Test_cluster" set admin_ip = "$newAaip" where admin_ip="$oldAaip";
update "Test_physical_volume" set connect_path ="$newAaip" where connect_path ="$oldAaip";
commit;
EOF
```

and I got the following error after `./updateDB.sh Aa`

```
change Aa database
Input dataBase password:
123456
Input old Aa ip:
1.1.1.1
Input new Aa ip:
1.1.1.2
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"Test_controller" set node_ip = "1.1.1.2" where node_ip="1.1.1.1"' at line 1
```

would somebody tell me why this happens?

Comment: Bash is trying to interpret text between `` `` as a command prefer ' or ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backtick is not a quotation sign, text between backticks is evaluated. So bash is trying to evaluate the command between backticks before your global command.

For your table name you don't need to escape your table name because it's not a reserved name. But if you need it, you have to also escape your backticks using `\` caracter.

Comment: I changed the backtick and some of the errors are gone, but still some exist. Would you please help to check if there's still something wrong with my bash syntax? The sql scripts did right in mysql command-line.

Comment: Can you try without " for the name of the table. Not sure you need it.

Comment: Yeap, your solution fixes all the errors,thanks very much. BTW, is it the shell who misunderstand the " or mysql who treat " as bad syntax?

Comment: In mysql, you can use ` to escape reserved name but in bash ` is evaluated so you have to escape ` in bash.